# Hover doesn't react to pointer accurately while working on button inside grid

Tags: html, css, button, grid, hover

I'm working on buttons then I have some errors with hover. There are 3 problems with my code.

In this picture, my pointer is at 20% button but 5% button seems to get hovered too.

Next, My pointer was at "Select Tip %", 5% still seems to get hovered.
Last picture, hover doen't work on Reset button
[image]

[image]

[image]

here is my code:

```css
.options {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 177.5px);
  gap: 20px;
}

.options button {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
  color: hsl(189, 41%, 97%);
}

.result-section .reset {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: hsl(172, 67%, 45%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: hsl(185, 41%, 84%);
}
```

```html
<label class="selections">
            <p >Select Tip &#37</p>
            <div class="options">
              <button class="a"  href="">5&#37</button>
              <button class="a"  href="">10&#37</button>
              <button class="a"  href="">15&#37</button>
              <button class="a"  href="">20&#37</button>
              <button class="a"  href="">25&#37</button>
              <input class="custom" type="number" placeholder="Custom">
            </div>
          </label>
<div class="items item-3">
  <button class="reset" href="">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change `label` tag to div and problem fixed!

```css
.options {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 177.5px);
  gap: 20px;
}

.options button {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
  color: hsl(189, 41%, 97%);
}

.result-section .reset {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: hsl(172, 67%, 45%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: hsl(185, 41%, 84%);
}
```

```html
<div class="selections">
            <p >Select Tip &#37</p>
            <div class="options">
              <button class="a"  href="">5&#37</button>
              <button class="a"  href="">10&#37</button>
              <button class="a"  href="">15&#37</button>
              <button class="a"  href="">20&#37</button>
              <button class="a"  href="">25&#37</button>
              <input class="custom" type="number" placeholder="Custom">
            </div>
          </label>
<div class="items item-3">
  <button class="reset" href="">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, can you tell why div make it work instead of label?